# Unable to save image in ImageView after DialogBox selection

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I want to save image in `ImageView` after click from camera or selecting it from gallery. I want to show  at least five image  and maximum eight image in my `Activity`.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {


    try {
        String file_path = "";
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                file_path = destination.getPath();
                editor.putString("image_path", file_path);
                editor.commit();

                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                    Picasso.with(Sell_Main.this).load(destination).into(imgone);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Sell_Main.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Sell_Main.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(Sell_Main.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


public void Image_Picker_Dialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myAlertDialog.setMessage("Select Picture Mode");

    myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
        {

            Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            pickPhoto.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
            startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);

        }
    });

    myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
        {
            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePicture.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
            startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
        }
    });
    myAlertDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: So, What is happening now?

Comment: what is error you get  ? please add Logcat first

Comment: i have first use case style it was working but it was slow ...the application was lagging .so i need to compress the image that i am taking from camera or gallery

Comment: and i also want a better  option to perform this task  as i hve a field for customer to upload image max 8 image so how can i design the layout .right now i have taken 8 image view side by side